# Best practice for using JSON and REST in an Android application?

Tags: android, json, rest

Last year I started to develop an Android application that uses JSON objects that are retrieved from a RESTful web service interface. In those days, I couldn't find a library or framework that could be used to parse JSON objects.

Are there any improvements over the last year? And is there a best practice how to handle JSON in combination with RESTful interfaces in an Android application?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE they said cache data in local storage and use it instead of direct call to REST service ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of JSON parsers out there which can be used in Android. Personally, I find Google's [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) works very nicely. I have also seen great results from [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but I have developed an open-source eclipse plugin for Android called Mechanoid that can generate REST clients using an easy to learn DSL.

It's still alpha but useful already and could turn out to be great if more folks took interest!

http://robotoworks.com/mechanoid-plugin/service-client-dsl/